# Xamarin.Forms Navigation.PushAsync Not Working

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project, and I have a custom control that should open a new page when tapped.  Unfortunately, nothing happens when I call `Navigation.PushAsync(...);`.  I've read countless StackOverflow questions ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007226/navigation-pushasyncnew-page-is-not-working-for-some-pages-in-xamarin-forms)) and Xamarin Forums threads and done several Google searches, but none of the solutions seem to solve my issue.

- My control inherits from `ContentView`, as all Xamarin.Forms views
  do.
- `src` is a custom class that contains some data points that
  are used by this control and `EventDetailsPage`.
- I can confirm that the gesture **does** work itself, but the call to `PushAsync()` does nothing.
- I have tried manipulating the statement in ways so that a `NavigationPage` is used (such that it becomes `myNavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new EventDetailsPage(src));`).
- I have also tried creating a constructor that takes a `Page` and uses it in away similar to the above point.

My control's constructor:

```
public EventControl() {
    InitializeComponent();
    GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() {
        Command = new Command(() => Navigation.PushAsync(new EventDetailsPage(src)))
    });
}
```

Typically, asking a new question on StackOverflow is my last resort when nothing else that I've tried solved my problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is your page actually contained inside of a NavigationPage?  And are you accessing the control's Navigation property, or the Navigation property of the page the control is contained within?

Comment: @Jason Yes.  My hierarchy goes `NavigationPage` -> `TabbedPage` -> `ContentPage` -> `ContentView` (as `EventControl`).  As for your second question, I've tried both.

Comment: Generally the TabbedPage will be your root, and each tab will contain a Nav page with a ContentPage inside of it (or just a ContentPage if that specific tab doesn't need Navigation).

Comment: @Jason I saw [this Xamarin Forums thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/176227/#Comment_176227) that warned that using `NavigationPage` inside `TabbedPage` was not recommended, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: @Jason I tried what you suggested, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I've tried a few things to reproduce your issue (not using a NavigationPage container, crashing in ctor or when Appearing or when other events are triggered)... but could not get it to silently fail. There must be something abnormal about your navigation environment or perhaps something happening inside of `EventDetailsPage` itself. Are you doing anything to override default behavior, such as hooking the `Pushed` event of the NavigationPage?

Comment: @KeithRome I found the issue.  I looked through the XAML of `EventDetailsPage` and I commented out another custom control (not related to `EventControl`) that I was using and that solved the problem.  I'm not sure why, but that control (it also had a custom renderer associated with it too) was causing that weird behavior.

Comment: I had the same issue, and my problem was because the page which I wanted to push had the error of referencing an image filename that was spelled incorrectly.  With this error, the push of that page failed silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  [Keith Rome lead me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906952/xamarin-forms-navigation-pushasync-not-working#comment59509793_35906952) to look through `EventDetailsPage` and I commented out a line of XAML, and that solved the problem.  That line was adding a custom control to the page (not related to `EventControl`).  I don't know if the control's definition or its custom render's definition was causing the strange behavior, but removing that line solved the issue.

Comment: hey greg did you found out any other solution to this issue other than removing custom control

Answer (score 19):

Change your **App.cs** like this

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());//Very important add this..
        //MainPage = new MainPage(); //not like this        
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me when navigating between Content Pages.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for different reasons...

I got this problem, after installing updates in Visual Studio, including Xamarin.

After updating all my nuget packages, by the following (the first command to show which ones have updates), I was able to resolve the problem:

```
Get-Package -updates
Update-Package <package>
```

I suspect, removing the AppData\local\Xamarin folder (which seems to act as a cache) and letting it repopulate could also solve the problem.

Comment: removing the AppData\local\Xamarin folder fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

this solved my problem

```
Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
     Navigation.PushAsync(new CameraPage());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented AppShell class which has one input string, in order to set correct page:

```
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell(string startUpPageString = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Page startUpPage;
            if (startUpPageString == nameof(SignUpPage))
            {
                startUpPage = new SignUpPage();
            }
            else if (startUpPageString == nameof(LoginPinPage))
            {
                startUpPage = new LoginPinPage();
            }
            else
            {
                startUpPage = new SignUpPage();
            }

            ShellSection shellSection = new ShellSection();
            shellSection.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = startUpPage });

            CurrentItem = shellSection;

            RegisterRoutes();
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            ...removed for clarity
        }
    }
```

among that, in my XAML I added some tabs (postlogin section) which are called though `GoToAsync(postlogin)` method:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:login="clr-namespace:XXX.Views.Login"
       xmlns:postlogin ="clr-namespace:XXX.XXX.Views.PostLogin"
       x:Class="XXX.AppShell"
       FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">


    <ShellItem Route="postlogin">
        <ShellSection Route="activity_section" Title="Activity" Icon="Activity_Menu_Icon.png">
            <ShellContent  Route="page1"
                      Title="Page1"
                      Icon="Pag1.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:Page1}" />
        </ShellSection>
 <ShellContent  Route="page2"
                      Title="Page2"
                      Icon="Pag2.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:Page2}" />
        </ShellSection>
 <ShellContent  Route="page3"
                      Title="Page3"
                      Icon="Page3.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:Page3}" />
        </ShellSection>
 <ShellContent  Route="page4"
                      Title="Page4"
                      Icon="Pag4.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate postlogin:Page4}" />
        </ShellSection>
    </ShellItem>

    <FlyoutItem Route="others"
                Title="OTHERS"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="cats"

                          Title="Cats"
                          Icon="next_7.png"
                       />
            <ShellContent Route="dogs"

                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="next_7.png"
                          />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

So, my problem is as follows: Once I got to for example, SignUpPage nad I click a button, and that button executes:
`await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new SentEmailPage());` it goews to catch part with an message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at Xamarin.Forms.ShellSection.OnPushAsync`